# Efficiency when splitting output from switching AC-DC power supply

Tags: dc, switch-mode-power-supply, efficiency

I have a number of electronic devices all of which require 12V DC input provided via a 2.1-5.5mm barrel jack.

Rather than have 3 separate AC to DC switching power supplies I'd like to use one power supply and then use a 2.1mm jack splitter to then power the individual devices

I've calculated the max total amperage will be 3A (by summing the amp requirements of each device).

As this is for an "always on" use-case I am conscious of designing the system to use as little power at wall as possible and minimise inefficiency.

My questions are:

1. If some or all of the devices are not operating at full power do switching power supplies use less power at the wall or do they always use their `Voltage * MaxAmperage + inefficiencies` worth of power?
2. Will the system use power if I over spec the power supplies, to say 5A for additional headroom?
3. Is a switching power supply the best tool for this use case, and if so is there any thing to look for when selecting a good one?

Thanks

Comment: 1) if current consumption was fixed, then what would be the point of having a rating such as `MaxAmperage`? ... `Amperage` would be sufficient

Comment: @jsotola I mean max amperage of the supply. I'll be honest, I don't really know how a switch mode power supply consumes current - does it only ever provide what is being consumed by the client devices?

A I guess another way of asking is if I have a 12V device requiring 1A and a 12V 3A supply - is it using 12W or 36W + inefficiencies at the wall?

Comment: @111111 A good PSU will have documentation which includes a load-vs-efficiency chart. The supply needs to be capable of supplying the maximum current requirement. Then look at the efficiency curves bearing in mind the *typical* current consumption.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the reply. The powersupply that I've attained doesn't have an easily accessible datasheet. However it does claim to meet 'Efficiency VI' standard. A quick google suggests that means it should be at least as good as: `≥ 0.071 x In(P out)-
0.0014 x Pout +0.67`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the power draw of your always-on devices is something you can’t change, all you can do is use the most efficient supply available, which would be a switching power supply.

1. If some or all of the devices are not operating at full power do switching power supplies use less power at the wall or do they always use their Voltage * MaxAmperage + inefficiencies worth of power?

No, they use Voltage * ActualAmperage + inefficiencies.
The actual current a “12V / 1A” device draws is typically less than 1A, usually much less.
The inefficiencies are in the power supply itself. A switching supply will typically have a fairly fixed efficiency in the 80-90% range, whereas a linear supply will have a widely varying efficiency typically <70% depending on load.

2. Will the system use power if I over spec the power supplies, to say 5A for additional headroom?

No. The system will draw only what it needs. Any extra current the supply is capable of supplying is just unused headroom.

3. Is a switching power supply the best tool for this use case, and if so is there any thing to look for when selecting a good one?

Yes. A switching supply is more efficient than a linear supply. You can look for the supply with the best efficiency but likely any differences will be small. A better place to look for power savings is in your devices themselves – can you idle them in a low power state, turn off LEDs, etc?

Comment: Thanks, all of the answer given to my question were correct but this was the most succinct so I've given you the green tick. Thanks everyone who has helped.

Answer (score 1):

1. The power supply will "waste" power at (1-efficiency) * Pout.  Some manufacturers will give you a maximum and/or minimum efficiency, while others will give you a curve.  See:
   https://www.cui.com/product/resource/vof-130-cnf.pdf
   Most of the converters I've seen have fairly similar curves with efficiency dropping modestly at low load.
2. 20% overhead current rating will probably only incur a 2-3% efficiency hit and is IMO worth it.
3. Without knowing your use case; this is impossible to answer accurately, but I can think of few cases in which grid power-to-12VDC would be better accomplished with something other than a switching power supply.

Comment: I assume that my power supply is reasonably typical. Going off the curves on page 3 it'd seem that the closer I get to the rated max current of the supply the more efficient that supply is. So whilst it will use less power when the devices are idling - the inefficiencies will be higher. So matching the power supply as closely the  max calculated load will give me the best efficiency, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, but I don't recommend running the power supply at 100% constantly.  20% overhead is probably appropriate unless you are running it at a high ambient temperature or some other limiting environmental constraint.  The difference in efficiency will be negligible, less than 1% if you're using the VOF-130, for example.  Note that the graph Y-axis starts at 60%.

Answer (score 1):

Let‘s have a look at how a switching PSU works.

In its simplest description, it has a switch and some kind of energy converting element (usually an inductor). The switch controls how much energy is transferred from input to output.

There are two kind of losses: Switching losses, which are small but constant, and resistive losses, which depend on output current. So the efficiency curve improves with increasing current, because the share of switching losses decreases. Usually ~90% is the best efficiency you can get.

So your plan of having only one switching PSU instead of many is good, because it maximizes efficiency.

You should not overspec too much, because efficiency decreases with low duty of the switching PSU.

A switching PSU is probably the best thing for voltage conversion. Cheap, easy, reliable and efficient.

One last advice: I noticed that a switching PSU with same specs as another one is more efficient if it is bigger in size. So size really matters :-)